# Angular route with parameters not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-webkit

I'd like to have an object as a parameter for my route but i'm starting with a number to test the route and it's not working.

Here are my routes :

```
// configure our routes
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                controller  : 'ApplicationController',
                templateUrl : './includes/home/home.html',
            })

            .when('/voir_message/:message', {
                templateUrl : './includes/messages/voir_message.html',
                controller : 'VoirMessagesController',
                controllerAs : 'controller'
            })

            .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    });
```

My controller :

```
app.controller('VoirMessagesController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, userService, dataRefreshServices){
    $scope.message = $routeParams.message;
});
```

When I need to change my route I use :

```
$location.path('voir_message/1');
```

Which don't work, when I click on my link (which calls a javascript function and call this line) my page is redirected to file:///

**1 -** Why ? If I remove the "/1" and the ":message" in the routes (so without passing any parameter) it works fine.

**2 -** After if I need to put my object, can I just put "JSON.stringify(myObject)" instead of "1" ?

**3 -** And last question about my routes, why does the address starts with "file:///" ? For example the index page is "file:///" (I'm using nodewebkit), so when I load the application I have the following error :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///
```

I found that the problem is with my main route, if I change "redirectTo : '/' the url is better but still have the error :

```
.when('/home', {
                controller  : 'ApplicationController',
                templateUrl : './includes/home/home.html',
            })

            .otherwise({redirectTo : '/home'});
```

**EDIT** my application :

```
var app = angular.module('client', ['ngRoute', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
```

used in my index.html like this :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="client">
```

Comment: Just a heads up : you're injecting $routeParams twice in your controller

Comment: Fixed but doesn't change anything

Comment: How do you access your application via browser?

Comment: Have you injected `ngRoute` into your app and all basic components, that are needed? In other words, need more code, otherwise I'm guessing.

Comment: I have injected ngRoute yes, I pasted the code of my module. The routes are working without parameters

Answer (score 0):

ok so i got this to work, but a few things need to be done for it to work correctly and more to test it correctly.

1. your setting up the html5 history api Im not 100% sure but this seems to be a part of the problem, and since with node-webkit you dont really see the url, no reason to need this. so i removed it. and it helped.

   `// use the HTML5 History API`
   `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
2. You are bootstrapping your app in the html with:
    `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="client">`
   using node-webkit i was unable to test the `$location` service without manually bootstrapping the angular app, so remove the `data-ng-app="client"` part.
3. because we removed the `ng-app` directive we now need to manually bootstrap the app in the code, which is perfect because bootstrapping the app returns the apps `dependencyInjector`, which we will need to test the `$location` service.
4. You are asking angular to load files from your file system when you put:
   `templateUrl : './includes/home/home.html',`
   inside of your route definition objects, where else would it load that file from? so instead of asking it to load the files from your file system, just give the html directly to your app using angulars html template syntax:
   `<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">`
   `<!-- your html for the template goes here -->`
   `</script>`

   then change your route definition objects templateUrl attribute to match the id of the script tag, ie: 
       `templateUrl : "home.html",`
5. once you make all of those changes there is only one more thing to keep in mind when changing angular views inside of a function:
   to change the view inside of a function in angular you must do 2 things:

   1. call the `path` method from the `$location` service, which you will need to grab it (and any other services you need to test ie: `$routeParams` and `$route`) using your apps `injector` that is returned when you call `angular.bootstrap` like this:

      `var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document.body,['client']);`
      `var $location = $injector.get("$location");`
      `// these arent from your example, but needed for testing`
      `var $route = $injector.get("$route");`
      `var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");`
      `var $routeParams = $injector.get("$routeParams");`
      `var $controller = $injector.get("$controller");`

      - now in your controller or wherever change the url with
        `$location.path("/voir_message/2");`
      - then to update the current route and its parameters call the `reload` method on the `$route` service.
        `$route.reload()`

now to actually test that it worked we need to load up the controller using the extra services we loaded a second ago, like this:

```
var ctrl = $controller('VoirMessageController',{'$scope':$rootScope.$new()});
```

and thats it, if you add a call to `console.log($scope);` inside of your controller you will see that the `$scope` now contains `{ 'message' : 2 }`

also, make sure you have `<ng-view></ng-view>` somewhere inside your index.html file, or angular wont load your routes when your app is bootstrapped